# Dispatch isn't called when I use bindActionCreators

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, redux

I'm able to get an input to update my redux store onChange if I explicitly write out the dispatch function. Why does it stop working when I try to use `bindActionCreators()`?

**not using bindActionCreators** (this works)

```
@connect(
  state => ({}),
  dispatch => {
    return {
      onSearchChange: (term) => {
        dispatch(search(term));
      }
    };
  }
)

export default class SearchForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={(event) => onSearchChange(event.target.value)} />
    );
  }
}
```

**using bindActionCreators** (this does not work. It never dispatches the action)

```
@connect(
  state => ({ categories: state.categories.data }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators({search}, dispatch)
);

export default class SearchForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={(event) => search(event.target.value)} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues here that seem to be syntactical and unrelated to Redux; they could be copy-paste errors, or actual issues:

1. Your second example contains a syntax error; there should not be a semicolon at the end of the decorator:

   > ```js
   > repl: Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration (4:1)
   >   2 |   state => ({ categories: state.categories.data }),
   >   3 |   dispatch => bindActionCreators({search}, dispatch)
   >   4 | );
   >     |  ^
   > ```
2. The functions you're calling in the event handler (in both examples) don't seem to be defined; for them to work as written, you'd need to extract the function from `this.props`:

   ```js
   export default class SearchForm extends Component {
     render() {
       const { search } = this.props;
       return (
         <input type="text" onChange={(event) => search(event.target.value)} />
       );
     }
   }
   ```

   If the examples are as written here in your code, I would expect the first example to fail unless there was an `onSearchChange` function declared in scope.

As a shortcut, `connect` can accept a simple object as a second argument, and it will assume each value on the object is an action creator for it to bind to:

```js
@connect(
  state => ({ categories: state.categories.data }),
  { search }
)
export default class SearchForm extends Component {
```

**[Edit]**

Since you import `search` via

```js
import {search} from 'redux/modules/repo-search';
```

you can import it instead with an alias

```js
import { search as searchActionCreator } from 'redux/modules/repo-search';
```

If you do this, then `connect` needs to know the value you really want to use for the prop:

```js
@connect(
  state => ({ categories: state.categories.data }),
  {search: searchActionCreator}
)
export default class SearchForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { search } = this.props;
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={(event) => search(event.target.value)} />
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively, simply use a different variable name, or the path to the function in `this.props`, inside `render`:

```js
return (
  <input type="text" onChange={(event) => this.props.search(event.target.value)} />
);
```

Comment: Thanks @michelle, this works! Do you know the correct way to set "search" to a constant in the render function? I've seen people do things like `const { categories, search } = this.props;` but that triggers the error `"search" is already declared in the upper scope` since I also have `import {search} from 'redux/modules/repo-search';` at the top of the file.

Comment: @DonnyP You can either import `search` with an alias (`import { member as alias } from "module-name";`) or give `search` inside `render` another name (`const doSearch = this.props.search`).

Comment: You can also just call `this.props.search(event.target.value)` inside the function you pass to `onChange`